# Converting unicode to "java

Tags: string, go, unicode, emoji

I have this a problem with character conversion. It all starts with this string: `U+1F618`. According to [fileformat.info](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f618/index.htm), this string is now (almost) in the `HTML Entity (hex)` notation.

But I need this character to be converted into a `C/C++/Java source code`-notation. I really don't know if this is the official name for the notation, but I assume this site to be correct :).

So basically my question is, instead of outputting to the real emoji, how can I get the value `\uD83D\uDE18`?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "html"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    original := "\\U0001f618"

    // Hex String
    h := strings.ReplaceAll(original, "\\U", "0x")

    // Hex to Int
    i, _ := strconv.ParseInt(h, 0, 64)

    // Unescape the string (HTML Entity -> String).
    str := html.UnescapeString(string(i))

    // Display the emoji.
    fmt.Println(str)

    // but I want something like this: \uD83D\uDE18
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the input as a `string`, e.g.

```
s := "\\U0001f618"
```

You may use [`strconv.Unquote()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Unquote) to unquote it. Be sure the string you pass to it is quoted (it must be wrapped with backticks or double quotes):

```
s2, err := strconv.Unquote(`"` + s + `"`)
fmt.Println(s2, err)
```

This will give you an `s2` string that contains your emoji:

```
 <nil>
```

Java's string model is a `char[]` which contains the [UTF-16 code points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16). Go's memory model of `string` is the [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoded byte sequence.

To convert a Go string to UTF-16, you may use the [`unicode/utf16`](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf16/) package of the standard lib. For example [`utf16.Encode()`](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf16/#Encode) encodes a series of `rune`s (unicode codepoints) to UTF-16. You get a series of runes from a Go `string` with a simple type [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions): `[]rune("some string")`.

```
u16 := utf16.Encode([]rune(s2))
fmt.Printf("%X\n", u16)
```

The above prints the UTF16 codepoints in hexadecimal format:

```
[D83D DE18]
```

To get the format you want, use this loop:

```
buf := &strings.Builder{}
for _, v := range u16 {
    fmt.Fprintf(buf, "\\u%X", v)
}
fmt.Println(buf.String())
```

Which outputs:

```
\uD83D\uDE18
```

Try the examples on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/U9JbYEbvKLo).

You can capture this series of conversions in a function:

```
func convert(s string) (string, error) {
    s2, err := strconv.Unquote(`"` + s + `"`)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    buf := &strings.Builder{}
    for _, v := range utf16.Encode([]rune(s2)) {
        fmt.Fprintf(buf, "\\u%X", v)
    }
    return buf.String(), nil
}
```

Using it:

```
fmt.Println(convert("\\U0001f618"))
```

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/6JOF8h3AFCT)):

```
\uD83D\uDE18 <nil>
```